# which file contains network configuration for MAAS?

Tags: networking, 16.04, maas

Ubuntu : 16.04

MAAS: 2.0.0 beta 3

Which file contains network configuration for MAAS?

Answer (score 0):

Technically all MAAS configuration is in PostgreSQL database named maasdb. You should change it via API, CLI or GUI. I wouldn't recommend to mess up with database directly.